# Trying to create a formula that will display results from a table based on responses from 2 dropdown boxes

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have 2 dropdown boxes.  Dropdown 1 has 11 possible choices.  Dropdown 2 has 20 choices.  Dropdown 1 will tell which table/range to pull numbers from.  Dropdown 2 will determine which set of numbers from the table/range to display.  I already have the 2 dropdowns working.  What I am trying to figure out now is how to have a set of 5 cells to display the numbers based on the choices made in the dropdowns.  If it helps to describe the usage, it is for a Dungeons and Dragons form for saving throws.  The class(dropdown 1) tells which set of numbers to look in, the level of the character(dropdown 2) tells which specific 5 numbers to display as the numbers lower as your level increases.
[image: Class and Level selected by user]

[image: Cells to list Saving Throws]

What I want is to display the correct scores in cells D15:D19 based on the class and level of the character.
[image: Saving Throw table]

I think I am close.  The lines below should individually check to see if the class(J8) matches and if a level(J9) was selected, and if so, print the correct stat in D15.  D15 should remain blank until both of the dropdowns are selected.  I just need to figure out how to combine all the lines into one formula in cell D15.

IF(J8="Fighter", IF(ISBLANK(J9),"",VLOOKUP(J9,'D&D Stats'!A22:B41,2))

IF(J8="Paladin", IF(ISBLANK(J9),"",VLOOKUP(J9,'D&D Stats'!A22:B41,2))

IF(J8="Ranger", IF(ISBLANK(J9),"",VLOOKUP(J9,'D&D Stats'!A22:B41,2))

IF(J8="Cavalier", IF(ISBLANK(J9),"",VLOOKUP(J9,'D&D Stats'!A22:B41,2))

IF(J8="Druid", IF(ISBLANK(J9),"",VLOOKUP(J9,'D&D Stats'!A68:B87,2))

IF(J8="Cleric", IF(ISBLANK(J9),"",VLOOKUP(J9,'D&D Stats'!A68:B87,2))

IF(J8="Mage", IF(ISBLANK(J9),"",VLOOKUP(J9,'D&D Stats'!A45:B64,2))

IF(J8="FighterMage", IF(ISBLANK(J9),"",VLOOKUP(J9,'D&D Stats'!A114:B133,2))

IF(J8="Thief", IF(ISBLANK(J9),"",VLOOKUP(J9,'D&D Stats'!A91:B110,2))

IF(J8="Rogue", IF(ISBLANK(J9),"",VLOOKUP(J9,'D&D Stats'!A91:B110,2))

IF(J8="Bard", IF(ISBLANK(J9),"",VLOOKUP(J9,'D&D Stats'!A91:B110,2))

The line below functions to check for "Fighter", check the Level and print the number in D15 and leave it blank if "Fighter" is not selected, but for some reason it only gets the correct number if level 1,2,18,19 or 20 is selected.  I don't understand why as all the numbers are in the range chart as shown in the image above. This is only to see if I can get any part to work. Obviously I need it to check for not just "Fighter", but each class.

=IF(J8="Fighter", IF(ISBLANK(J9),"",VLOOKUP(J9,'D&D Stats'!A22:B41,2)),IF(ISBLANK(J9),"",""))

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off unpivoting your table and then using QUERY to break it all down. If you shift everything over to the right one column and fill A with the class, you can do this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(COUNTA(B2:B4)<>3,,
   IFERROR(
    QUERY(
     SPLIT(
      FLATTEN(data!A2:A&"|"&data!C1:G1&"|"&data!B2:B&"|"&data!C2:G),
      "|",TRUE,TRUE),
     "select Col4
      where
       Col4 is not null and
       Col1 = '"&B2&"' and
       Col2 = '"&B3&"' and
       Col3 = "&B4&""))))
```

This assumes you have the following:

- B2 = Class
- B3 = Weapons (poison, rod, breath, spell, etc)
- B4 = Level

You can modify it to suit your needs, but it should work nicely.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will look into that and see if I can make it work.

Comment: If it works out, can you upvote and mark it as answered. If you'd like a demo, I can whip one up for you.

Comment: I would be interested in a demo. Right now I am not seeing how it would work. I need a formula in cell D15 that takes the class selected by a drop-down in J8 and the level selected by a drop-down in J9 all on the sheet called Character, and looks up the correct number from the table which is on a separate sheet called Saving Throws, and displays that number in D15 on the Character sheet. I would then need the same for cells D16-D19 which will show the other 4 saving throws. I made a table with the class in column A.  With 11 classes and 20 levels, the full table is 220 rows with 7 columns.

Comment: Check [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C3hUexLGS6BJYR_dGuzJQFvygidQgMTUGNTbb1IZ60Q/edit?usp=sharing) -- it's a little different than the one above, but the sheet should make sense. Expand the formula bar, since the formulas are formatted.

Comment: I see it is a similar concept but I need to put the right info in the specific cells with only the input of the class and level provided by the player. When a character levels up and changes the level, the saving throws need to update automatically to the 5 cells already there.  I copied the actual character sheet and the equipment sheet that has the classes over to the one you shared to me.  Also included the full listing of saving throws for all classes.  Maybe if you look at the full sheets it would help.  It seems to me it may need to be a separate formula for each of the 5 cells D15-D19.

Comment: Can you share a sheet? It'll be the same sort of idea, just change data!C1:G1 and data!C2:G to match the width of your sheet and add in more `where Col# = '"&cell reference&"'`. Also change `IF(COUNTA(B2:B4)<>3,,` to match the range of your inputs with the total number of inputs required before it returns a value.

Comment: I did copy the full character sheet along with the 2 sheets it uses to pull data from to the sheet you had shared to me as an example. The sheets are Character, Equipment and Saving Throws. J8 and J9 on Character are the Class and Level respectively and I believe it's D15-D19 that are the cells that will need formulas. On the Saving Throws sheet there are 7 columns with A being the class, B being the level and each Save being columns C-G. So D15 needs to pull from column C on Saving Throws , D16 from column D on Saving Throws and so on.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet with edits open? It'd be easier to work with.

Comment: I shared it to you.  It's called Test Copy.

Comment: ok cool. That same general formula will work for all of that. Its just narrowing things down. I updated the formula on the output sheet. You can use that and change the 'where' portion to filter down your dataset to the value you want returned. I also included a sample of the ideal dataset -- its what is being created in the background. That sort of layout is what spreadsheets prefer.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to help.  Unfortunately I just can't get it to work.  Your example has 3 drop downs, one of which selects info that in not selectable in mine. The one you have labeled as "output" would in mine be labeled Death/Poison and is only looking for the number from column C of the saving throw sheet where column A and column B match the Class and Level selected by my 2 drop downs.  It seems odd  it's so hard to get a formula or lookup that would just check that column A and column B match with the input and simply return the number from column C in the same row. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I added one more sheet to the one you shared to me, just called sheet4.  I put a much more basic version of what I am looking for if you want to take a look at it.  All the data is on the same sheet.

Comment: Thanks again for trying to help.  I got help from someone on another site.  Turned out that a query was the answer.     =QUERY('Saving Throws'!A1:G,"select C where A = '"&J8&"' and B='"&J9&"' ",0)   This checks my data for match in columns A and B and gives me C without any need to change the structure of my data sheet.